# Who are the dogs in Philippians 3:2 and Revelation 22:15?

Tags: greek, hebrew, hebrew-bible, new-testament, metaphor

Deuteronomy 23:18 says

> Thou shalt not bring the hire of a whore, or the price of a dog, into the house of the LORD thy God for any vow: for even both these are abomination unto the LORD thy God. (KJV)

Now looking at my Strong's concordance (H3611), and some other english translations, they refer to the "dog" in Deuteronomy 23:18 being a male prostitute.

In terms of human behaviour/activity, what are the authors meaning with the use of the word "dog" for the following New Testament verses?

> Beware of dogs, beware of evil workers, beware of the concision. Philippians 3:2 (KJV)
>
> For without are dogs, and sorcerers, and whoremongers, and murderers, and idolaters, and whosoever loveth and maketh a lie.  Revelation 22:15 (KJV)

My Strong's concordance has the Greek word just meaining "dog" (G2965).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "dog" in the NT is κύων (kuón) and only occurs 5 times and always in a contemptuous way.  The animal was universally reviled in Bible times and always symbolised things hated, impure, sinful and disgusting.  They are comparable to pigs in the eyes of Jews (2 Peter 2:22).

- In Matt 7:6 the dog is a symbol of "a cultically impure person" (BDAG)
- In Luke 16:21 literal dogs are described as licking the sores in the parable of the rich man and Lazarus.  This is a supremely disgusting scene to NT culture.
- Phil 3:2 - dogs are symbols of evil, "infamous people" (BDAG).
- 2 Peter 2:22 - the dog returning to its vomit is as contemptuous as a person who is once saved and then rejects Jesus' salvation (v20, 21).  See also Prov 26:11.
- Rev 22:15 - Dogs outside the city are used as symbols of the unsaved, infamous people.  See also Ps 59:14.

Exactly the same attitude is found in the OT - see Judges Eccl 9:4, 1 Sam 17:43, 2 Sam 3:8, 9:8, 16:9, 2 Kings 8:13, Ps 22:16, 20, Prov 26:11, 17, Isa 56:10, etc.

In Deut 23:18 the Hebrew word כֶּ֗לֶב (keleb) indeed means "dog" but is used symbolically to denote the very low cultic and social status of a male prostitute.  Some translations make this explicit.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense that a dog simply means "unclean" in this verse. From my Complete Jewish Bible (CJB), Revelations 22:15 says "outside are the homosexuals".

1. Homosexuals and those involved with the
2. Occult
3. Drugs
4. Sexually immoral
5. Murderers
6. Idol-worshippers
7. and everyone who practices falsehood

1 Corinthians 6:9-10 says

1. Unrighteous (this should be anyone not saved through the blood of Jesus)
2. Fornicators
3. Idolaters
4. Adulterers
5. Homosexuals (KJV Effeminate)
6. Sodomites (abusers of themselves with mankind)
7. Thieves
8. Covetous
9. Drunkards
10. Revilers
11. Extortioners

Most of the sins are financially related or sexually related, with God-hating what is "abominable"

Leviticus 18:22 - "You shall not lie with a male as with a woman; it is an abomination."

Leviticus 20:13 - "If a man lies with a male as with a woman, both of them have committed an abomination; they shall surely be put to death; their blood is upon them."

Deuteronomy 22:5 - “A woman shall not wear a man's garment, nor shall a man put on a woman's cloak, for whoever does these things is an abomination to the Lord your God."

Deuteronomy 23:18 -"You shall not bring the fee of a prostitute or the wages of a dog into the house of the Lord your God in payment for any vow, for both of these are an abomination to the Lord your God."

Now ask yourself, why is money earned as a prostitute as bad as wages of a dog? The Complete Jewish Bible has dog properly interpreted as homosexual.

> <sup>**18**</sup> Nothing earned through heterosexual or homosexual prostitution is to be brought into the house of ADONAI your God in fulfillment of any vow, for both of these are abhorrent to ADONAI your God."

Furthermore, you have Romans chapter 1, particularly 26-27

Romans 1:26-27

> <sup>**26**</sup> Because of this, God gave them over to shameful lusts. Even their women exchanged natural sexual relations for unnatural ones. <sup>**27**</sup> In the same way the men also abandoned natural relations with women and were inflamed with lust for one another. Men committed shameful acts with other men, and received in themselves the due penalty for their error.

When you use the entire Bible for context of who is not going to heaven, it points more to "homosexuals" rather than just a dog (immorality) since there are specifics everywhere else pointing to no dogs, but homosexual/effeminate men.

I found this helpful as well researching your answer as I had my own questions:

[STRONGS NT 2965: κύων](https://biblehub.com/greek/2965.htm)

> κύων, κυνός; in secular authors of the common gender, in the N. T. masculine; Hebrew כֶּלֶב; a dog; properly: Luke 16:21; 2 Peter 2:22; metaphorically (in various (but always reproachful) senses; often so even in Homer) a man of impure mind, an impudent man (cf. Lightfoot on Phil. l. s.): Matthew 7:6; Philippians 3:2; Revelation 22:15, in which last passage others less probably understand sodomites (like כִּלָבִים in Deuteronomy 23:18 (19)) (cf. B. D., under the word ).

Comment: Hi C.J, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Comment: Very good, hermeneutically correct, answer.  I would have answered almost the same, +1.  The only thing I would have added is that the Bible uses euphemisms to address some things too objectionable to be explicitly named, and this is one of those.  When we see dogs in nature, a male dog will often mount another male--whether in play or lust, who knows, yet the Bible seems to illustrate its meaning by this apt analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

A dog licks with the tongue.  A person flatters others with the tongue.

A “dog” is a person who flatters others by speaking great swelling words of emptiness in order to lead them astray.

The “dogs” spoken about in Philippians 3:2 are leaders… “shepherds”.  Beware of dogs….beware of evil workers….beware of the “concision”....that is,  the “cutting off”.

> Philippians 3:2 KJV **(2)  Beware of dogs, beware of evil workers,
>   beware of the concision.**

The person who is a “dog” is the spiritual equivalent of the “Amalek” which means the “people who lick”.   They flatter others with the tongue….they “lick”.

Just as new Christians are escaping the pollutions of this world (“Egypt”), they (the Amalekites…the dogs) come forth and meet us by the Way (the Way of righteousness) in order to “smite the hindmost” of us.

This is the “concision”…the cutting off of us from the Way of righteousness that leads us to His eternal life in this earth.  "By the Way" = by the Way of righteousness.

> Deuteronomy 25:17-19 KJV (17)  *Remember what Amalek did unto thee **by
>   the way,** when ye were come forth out of Egypt*;

The “dogs” flatter others with the tongue in order to “cut off”…the concision…. from the Way of righteousness that leads to life those who become “faint and weary” in well doing.

Of course, they do this for money’s sake (the price of a dog as mentioned in Deuteronomy 23:18).    Interestingly, “smote the hindmost” also means “to wag”….as a dog does with the tail.

"he met you by the Way" = by the Way of righteousness that we know to take.

> (18)  ***How he met thee by the way, and smote the hindmost of thee, even
>   all that were feeble behind thee, when thou wast faint and weary;*** and
>   he feared not God. (19)  Therefore it shall be, when the LORD thy God
>   hath given thee rest from all thine enemies round about, in the land
>   which the LORD thy God giveth thee for an inheritance to possess it,
>   that thou shalt blot out the remembrance of Amalek from under heaven;
>   thou shalt not forget it.

The “dogs” who “lick” speak great swelling words of emptiness with their tongues to those who are just escaping the pollutions of the world (coming out of Egypt).

> 2 Peter 2:18-22 KJV (18)  ***For when they speak great swelling words of
>   vanity,*** they allure through the lusts of the flesh, through much
>   wantonness, those that were clean escaped from them who live in error.
>   (19)  While they promise them liberty, they themselves are the
>   servants of corruption: for of whom a man is overcome, of the same is
>   he brought in bondage.

They meet us by the Way of righteousness in order to cut off those who become faint in weary in well doing….who are just escaping the pollutions of the world (Egypt).

"escaped the pollutions of the world" = coming out of Egypt.

> (20)  ***For if after they have escaped the pollutions of the world***
>   through the knowledge of the Lord and Saviour Jesus Christ, they are
>   again entangled therein, and overcome, the latter end is worse with
>   them than the beginning.

Beware of the “concision”….the cutting off from the Way of righteousness by the spiritual “Amalekites”….the people who lick...the people who flatter with the tongue…the “dogs”.

The “Amalekites” meet us by the Way….the Way of righteousness…in order to cut off (the “concision”) those who are “feeble”….unsteady in it.

They use flattery to cut off from the Way those who become “faint and weary” in well doing.  It would have been better to not have known the Way of righteousness then to turn from it after knowing the Way of righteousness.

> (21)  *F**or it had been better for them not to have known the way of
>   righteousness,** than, after they have known it, to turn from the holy
>   commandment delivered unto them.*

The “dogs” want us to keep their handwriting of church dogmas (the carnal commandments and teachings of men) and use them to fight with others….which is not doing the Holy Commandment to have love for one another.   They want to bring us into their church bondage and return to the envying and striving with one another  (in their denominations)  just as the world behaves in that does not know the Way.

> (22)  *But it is happened unto them according to the true proverb, The
>   dog is turned to his own vomit again; and the sow that was washed to
>   her wallowing in the mire.*

Be not deceived.  He that sows after the flesh (in the envy and strife with one another), shall of the mortal flesh reap decay of the mortal flesh but he that continues to sow to the Spirit shall of the Spirit reap life everlasting as the Spirit shall make alive our mortal bodies in this earth.

This manifest life in our outer mortal flesh is the eternal  life of Jesus appearing in this world for all to see who will then glorify God in Heaven.   The “dogs” have no knowledge of this.  If they knew, they would not crucify the Lord of glory….preventing His life from ever appearing in this world because of their feigned words of emptiness which deceive many and leads them down the broad way to their mortal destruction.

> Galatians 6:7-10 KJV (7)  Be not deceived; God is not mocked: for
>   whatsoever a man soweth, that shall he also reap. (8)  **For he that
>   soweth to his flesh shall of the flesh reap corruption; but he that
>   soweth to the Spirit shall of the Spirit reap life everlasting.**

Let us not be “weary” in well doing for in dues season we shall reap if we faint not.   If we become “faint and weary”, then the “dogs” that come forth have the power to deceive us and lead us astray from the Way of righteousness that leads to that everlasting life for our mortal bodies in this earth.

> (9)  ***And let us not be weary in well doing:*** for in due season we shall
>   reap, if we faint not. (10)  As we have therefore opportunity, **let us
>   do good unto all men,** especially unto them who are of the household of
>   faith.

They come forth posing as ministers of righteousness in order to cut us off from the Way that leads to life.  Broad is the way that leads to destruction (of the mortal body from this earth) and MANY are going (now) through it.

> Matthew 7:12-15 KJV (12)  *Therefore all things whatsoever ye would
>   that men should do to you, do ye even so to them: for this is the law
>   and the prophets. (13)  Enter ye in at the strait gate: for wide is
>   the gate, **and broad is the way, that leadeth to destruction, and many
>   there be which go in thereat:** (14)  **Because strait is the gate, and
>   narrow is the way, which leadeth unto life,** and few there be that find
>   it.*

They are seizing many who are listening to them.

> (15)  **Beware of false prophets, which come to you in sheep's clothing,
>   but inwardly they are ravening wolves.**

They are “shepherds”…..greedy “dogs” which can never have enough.  They are shepherds that cannot understand as they all look to their own way…their own profit.

> Isaiah 56:10-12 KJV (10)  *His watchmen are blind: they are all
>   ignorant, they are all dumb dogs, they cannot bark; sleeping, lying
>   down, loving to slumber. (11)  **Yea, they are greedy dogs which can
>   never have enough, and they are shepherds that cannot understand:** they
>   all look to their own way, every one for his gain, from his quarter.*

They want you to come rejoice with them as they become rich off of our expense as they promise abundance for us.

> (12)  *Come ye, say they, I will fetch wine, and we will fill ourselves
>   with strong drink; and to morrow shall be as this day, and much more
>   abundant.*

They say that they are sent by Christ (“apostles” = sent) but they are instead the ministers of Satan who  are transformed as the ministers of righteousness (coming to us in sheep’s clothing).

> 2 Corinthians 11:12-15 KJV (12)  *But what I do, that I will do, that I
>   may cut off occasion from them which desire occasion; that wherein
>   they glory, they may be found even as we. (13)  **For such are false
>   apostles, deceitful workers, transforming themselves into the apostles
>   of Christ.** (14)  And no marvel; for Satan himself is transformed into
>   an angel of light.*

Their end is according to their works.  Their end is the destruction of their mortal body from this earth…and they lead many along with them who are deceived by their good words and fair speeches down the same path of destruction.  They are the pied pipers of death so to speak.

> (15)  **Therefore it is no great thing if his ministers also be
>   transformed as the ministers of righteousness; whose end shall be
>   according to their works.**

The “dogs” are outside as they have no understanding of the Scriptures.  They cannot enter in to know the mysteries of the kingdom because of their activities as they lead many astray from the Way that leads to life (they do not have the right to the tree of life).

> Revelation 22:14-15 KJV (14)  *Blessed are they that do his
>   commandments, that they may have right to the tree of life, and may
>   enter in through the gates into the city. (15)  **For without are dogs,**
>   and sorcerers, and whoremongers, and murderers, and idolaters, and
>   whosoever loveth and maketh a lie.*

They lead many astray….and the whole spiritually-poor church body has “sores” of which they “lick” by proclaiming with their tongues “peace, peace” when there is none.

> Luke 16:20-22 KJV (20)  *And there was a certain beggar named Lazarus,
>   **which was laid at his gate, full of sores,** (21)  And desiring to be
>   fed with the crumbs which fell from the rich man's table: **moreover the
>   dogs came and licked his sores.***

The rich pastors come and “heal the hurt” of the daughter of His people slightly saying “peace, peace” when there is no peace.   The dogs came and licked the sores of Lazarus.

> Jeremiah 8:10-11 KJV (10)  *Therefore will I give their wives unto
>   others, and their fields to them that shall inherit them: **for every
>   one from the least even unto the greatest is given to covetousness**,
>   from the prophet even unto the priest every one dealeth falsely. (11) 
>   **For they have healed the hurt of the daughter of my people slightly,
>   saying, Peace, peace; when there is no pea**ce*.

Those who are spiritually hungering to be fed with the Word of Truth only hear “crumbs” from the rich pastors who care nothing for the church that they are in charge of.  They lay at the “gate”….their mouth…waiting to hear the Word of Truth.    Yet, the rich pastors fare “sumptuously every day” while many are not being fed with the Word of God spoken in sincerity and truth.

> Luke 16:19-21 KJV (19)  *There was a certain rich man, which was
>   clothed in purple and fine linen, and fared sumptuously every day:
>   (20)  **And there was a certain beggar named Lazarus, which was laid at
>   his gate, full of sores**, (21)  And desiring to be fed with the crumbs
>   which fell from the rich man's table: moreover the dogs came and
>   licked his sores.*

But the Lord comes to deliver us from them so that we may be healed.

Answer (score -1):

Jesus referred to a woman and her daughter as being dogs.
Those dogs are the non-Adamic people. They are of a mixed
bloodline from the fallen angels who came from the dog star
sirius which is why Jesus called her a dog. He was denoting
her origin. Most people on this earth today are dogs. Jesus
said every plant my heavenly father has not planted will
be removed.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  Do you have a reference for your assertion about "dogs are the non-Adamic people".  I have never seen that in the Bible.

Comment: 'Fallen angels from the dog star sirius' requires support from scripture. I can find  none, myself. So also with 'most people on this earth today are dogs' which requires support from scripture. Again, I can find none.